# Configuring PHP for MySQL after installing Apache & PHP from source in Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have already installed Apache 2.4.4 & PHP 5.4 from source in my Ubuntu 10.04 machine. I also installed MySQL 5.6 from source and SQL commands are running from shell.

When I use an SQL function to connect to database, it throws a fatal error that this function is not defined.

I know I can configure PHP for MySQL by providing the directory of MySQL while installing PHP, but now I have already installed & configured Apache & PHP and they are working, so please tell me how to configure PHP for MySQL support.

Thanks.

Comment: which sql function are you running and what it returns?

Comment: mysql_connect(), but I think it does not matter as php does not know where I have installed mysql. It will throw error for any mysql function.

Comment: mysql_connect() , when run browser has a error message Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect().

Answer (score 0):

Recompile php with --with-mysql OR --with-mysqli directive. This way you can add required extensions to php. See [php-mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php)  OR [php-mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)

Comment: Is there not any other option where I have not to recompile it? As I think this will include some overhead of copying php ini files to /usr/local/lib and edit some other configurations or just a recompilation needed?

Comment: Personally I think recompiling should be your only option as you compile already php. However you can try to enable mysql.so or mysqli.so in php.ini and restart apache if it can works.